# Whatt kind of make and model is this suv?

Tags: vehicle-identification, suv

[image: rear end of veh]

rear end of unknown type of make and model of this vehicle in photo

Comment: Do you have a larger version of the photo? It's very dark and the one in the post is too small/low res to really do anything with.

Comment: Judging by the tail light alone (only thing I can really see in the image), it's a [Mustang Mach-E EV](https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/2024-ford-mustang-mach-e-rally-2-64f8805a9ed2d.jpg). That is of course a SWAG, but all I got.